# Regex for router paths

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a case where I need a regex to match following paths:

```
path="/"
path="/one"
path="/two"
path="/one/123hash2312" // some random hash after one/
path="/two/232hash43"   // some random hash after two/
```

I tried `/(one|two)?` but it doesnt let me use the hash after one and two. Looking for help

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to isolate, but are you escaping any slashes? Or you might try something like  /^path="(.*)"/gm

Answer (score 1):

```
/^\/(one|two)(/\w+)?$/
```

should work for you

Comment: It doesnt match anything, even the `/` path

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```js
const regex = /^\/(one|two)?\/?(\w*)$/;

[
"/",
"/one",
"/two",
"/one/123hash2312",
"/two/232hash43",
].forEach( str => console.log(regex.exec(str)) )
```